# Asking the user to input a number and asking them again if they never put in a number in the first place C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that will ask the user to enter a number. I have coded that, but what I am struggling to add is a part where it will ask the user again if they entered a character or never answered the question in the first place. I want this done to all my questions that I ask them since they are all asking for an Integer.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("---welcome to split my bill---");
      Console.Write("What is the total bill?: £");
      float bill_total = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.Write("How many people are sharing?:");
      int people = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.Write("What percentage tip would you like to leave?:");
      float tip_percentage = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

      float percentage_decimal = tip_percentage/100;
      float tip_total = bill_total * percentage_decimal;
      bill_total = bill_total + tip_total;

      float CostPerPerson = bill_total/people;

      Console.WriteLine("Total Bill including tip is: £"+bill_total);
      Console.WriteLine("Total cost per person is: £"+CostPerPerson);
        
        }
      }
```

any help?

Comment: use a `while` loop to check if the input is valid and when it is valid use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: and don't forget to allow Q or something to quit  =)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out using an If statment. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: When dealing with currency (money), `decimal` is the better datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are learning C#, think a bit more general and write a function to handle user inputs with repeats if they type something wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float totalBill = AskForNumber("What is the total bill?");
    }

    static float AskForNumber(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (float.TryParse(input, out float value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: scr]

The problem with the above method is that the user has no way of exiting the program unless they press `Ctrl-C` which is not very graceful.

You need to learn of about `out` parameters for functions, and then you can write the function to input a value and return `true` if the program should proceed, or `false` if it needs to exit. The value itself is assigned to the variable designated with the `out` keyword.

Below is an example of the whole process. Each step proceeds only if the previous function returned `true`. If a user enters a blank line, then the program will exit as the return value is going to be 'false' and the program is not going to continue inside the `if()` statement.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (AskForNumber("What is the total bill?", out float totalBill))
        {
            if (AskForInteger("How many people are sharing?", out int people))
            {
                if (AskForNumber("What percentage tip would you like to leave?", out float tipPercent))
                {
                    float tip_total = totalBill * (tipPercent/100);
                    totalBill += tip_total;

                    float costPerPerson = totalBill/people;

                    Console.WriteLine("Total Bill including tip is: £"+totalBill);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total cost per person is: £"+costPerPerson);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static bool AskForNumber(string prompt, out float value)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (float.TryParse(input, out value))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (input.Length == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Try again.");
        }
    }
    static bool AskForInteger(string prompt, out int value)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input, out value) && value>0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (input.Length == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: scr2]